# Converting a PDF text(any language) content to Html

Tags: reactjs, wkhtmltopdf

I am planning to develop an React Application to publish stories,articles kind of contents.
I am wondering if there is any way to read the content from PDF and convert it to HTML and show it in my own style. Instead of  typing the whole 1000s of text,paragraphs or showing the content as a PDF viewer.

Simplify my question.. I want to show the content from the PDF document to website in my own text styling.but don't want to use the PDF viewer libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse PDF data as text with https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ and style it however you'd like

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer but the link is not working.

Comment: OK I got it. Thank you so much I will give it a try.